# what is the wrong with my PHP/AJAX/jQuery login script?

Tags: php, forms, jquery, authentication

what is the wrong with my PHP/AJAX/jQuery login script?

I have this code:

dologin.php file is:

```
<?php

$is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax) {

    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

    if($username == 'demo' && $password == 'demo') {
        echo "success";
    }
}
?>
```

index.php file is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type= "text/javascript" scr= "jquery.latest.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(documnt).ready(function) {

    $('#login').click(function) {

        var action = $("#form1").attr("action");
        var form_data = {
         username: $("#username").val(),
         password: $("#password").val(),
         is_ajax: 1         
    };

    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: action,
       data: form_data, 
       success: function(response)
        {
            if(response == 'success')
            {
                $("form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                $("#message").html('<p class="success"> You have logged in. </p>');
              });
              }
               else 
               $("#message").html('<p class="error"> Invalid username and/or password. </p>');
                }

    });
    return false;
 });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>    
<div id="content"> 
 <h1>Login form</h1>   

    <form name="form1" id="form1"  method="post" action="dologin.php">
        <p>
            <label for="username"> Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="usernmae" />
        </p>
        <p>
             <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" name="password" /> 
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Login" />
        </p>
    </form>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It keep giving me this error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: is_ajax in C:\wamp\www\final project\passnumber\dologin.php on line 3
```

I'm new at AJAX and jQuery, please would you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: `var form_data - {` think that should be `=` and not `-` for starters

Comment: Is this just a typo here or is it your actual code? `var form_data - {`

Comment: I would say it's this:  `var form_data - {`, except I'd expect the javascript to error as well.

Comment: Thank you guys, I've corrected it, but nothing changed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just seeing a blank white page that usually means that you have a syntax error with your php. Or you have not added anything to that page.

Here is what is working for me:

I have a page in a directory called test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var action = '';
    var form_data = '';
    $('#login').click(function () {
         action = $("#form1").attr("action");
         form_data = {
         username: $("#username").val(),
         password: $("#password").val(),
         is_ajax: '1'};  

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: action,
            data: form_data, 
            success: function(response) {
                 if(response == 'success') {
                   $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                     $("#message").html('<p class="success"> You have logged in. </p>');
                   });
                 } else { 
                    $("#message").html('<p class="error"> Invalid username and/or password. </p>');
                 }
            }

         }); 
        return false;      
    });  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="message">&nbsp;</p>    
<div id="content"> 
 <h1>Login form</h1>   

    <form name="form1" id="form1"  method="post" action="dologin.php">
        <p>
            <label for="username"> Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="usernmae" />
        </p>
        <p>
             <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /> 
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Login" />
        </p>
    </form>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In that same directory I have a php file called dologin.php

```
$is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax) {

    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

    if($username == 'demo' && $password == 'demo') {
        echo "success";
    } 
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I appreciate your kind help.. :)

Answer (score 3):

The index `is_ajax` does not exist in the array `$_REQUEST`.

You should verify it this way:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']) 
{
    #Do something. For instance:
    $myVar = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
}
else
{
    return "Something went wrong";
}
```

---

You **also** have a **syntax error** in your JavaScript object.

`form_data - {...}` *should be* `form_data = {...}`

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help..! The weird thing that I copied it from this tutorial goo.gl/15wjF

Comment: Do you have any error popping up in your console or PHP errors?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong, you are setting a variable and getting a warning and after that you are using `isset` to check if the variable you just set, is set.

You should change:

```
$is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax) {
```

to something like:

```
$is_ajax = isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']) && $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
if($is_ajax) {
```

And you have typo in your javascript, an `-` that should be an `=`.

**Edit:** You should double-check all your javascript, as the first line should read:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

instead of:

```
$(documnt).ready(function) {
```

Comment: I've used your code, the error has been gone, but nothing happened or showed at all..!

Comment: It gave me: array (size=3)
  'usernmae' => string 'demo' (length=4)
  'password' => string 'demo' (length=4)
  'login' => string 'Login' (length=5)

Comment: @MRAN You should check your javascript for errors and typos as it seems it is not running and you are submitting your form the normal way (without ajax). Note for example the first line, it should be `$(document).ready(function() {`.

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing submitted with the name `is_ajax`, so it is an undefined index in your code.

Comment: What is the resolution, then?

Answer (score 0):

To check if it's an ajax request, try this:

```
function isAjax() {
    return !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}
```

Anyway, if you are not sure if a key in array exists, do isset() before you assign it to any variable.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to show you the difference so just try this instead of your jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var action = '';
    var form_data = '';
    $('#login').click(function () {
         action = $("#form1").attr("action");
         form_data = {
         username: $("#username").val(),
         password: $("#password").val(),
         is_ajax: '1'};  

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: action,
            data: form_data, 
            success: function(response) {
                 if(response == 'success') {
                   $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                     $("#message").html('<p class="success"> You have logged in. </p>');
                   });
                 } else { 
                    $("#message").html('<p class="error"> Invalid username and/or password. </p>');
                 }
            }

         }); 
        return false;      
    });  
});
```

Comment: Did you replace your javascript with this javascript?

Comment: My only other change was adding a adding a doctype at the top <!DOCTYPE>, typically getting a white page is a usually a PHP issue. Using your code with my updated js their should be no php on the page.

Comment: I've added all of these as it shown in the video tutorial (goo.gl/15wjF):<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: What did you mean, please? `typically getting a white page is a usually a PHP issue. Using your code with my updated js their should be no php on the page`

Comment: I will post code in a new comment because it is too long to post here.